# Ending a sentence with さ

Tags: usage, particles

When is it appropriate to put さ at the end of a sentence? Do women say this also? I think I remember seeing a female character say it in an anime.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In standard Japanese, ending with a さ is a colloquial way to make a statement more playfully assertive. After a Hanshin victory over the Tokyo Giants, a Hanshin fan might say:

> まあ阪神のほうが強いからな。

or

> まあ阪神の方が強いのさ。

To preserve the tone, I might translate the first version as a flat statement of opinion, as in:

> Well, Hanshin *is* the stronger team.

while the second version might be more of a playful burn, like

> Well, Hanshin is the stronger team: fact!

It's not rude, but it is assertive, and colloquial, so I wouldn't use it with a superior. It's gender-neutral. If it seems to be employed slightly more by Japanese men than by Japanese women, that's just true of assertiveness in general.

Comment: It should be noted this is a feature of the Kanto regional dialect. People in Yamagata or Kansai don't really use it さ〜

Comment: @crunchyt: Hmm, are you sure? I've only heard it used from speakers (in life and works of fiction) who had been speaking standard Japanese. Or did you mean "Kanto dialect" in the general sense, as including the Tokyo dialect/standard Japanese?

Comment: Yeah i mean it in the sense of 標準語 (ひょうじゅんご), I should've been clearer :)

Comment: −1: You should use Chunichi instead of Hanshin.  (I’m kidding)

Answer (score 4):

さ　can be used by both males and females.  Though my dictionary says mainly masculine and used for assertion.

Comment: Plus the dialects change the usage of this sound a lot. Ie, in Osaka, children and young people use it at the end of the sentence as a crutch or speech style. So what we hear can be either standard or dialect.

Answer (score 1):

Jisho.org has the following definition:

**さ**

*Suffix*

1. *-ness*  ​nominalizing suffix indicating degree or condition

   そして、どうすることも出来ない物憂**さ**に、ふっとため息をつく。

   And then I breathe a sigh from melancholy in being unable to do anything about it.

*Particle*

2. *indicates assertion*  ​sentence end, mainly masc.

   ベストをつくしたら後はくよくよ考えないこと**さ**。

   Do your best and don't worry.
3. *come; come now*​ See also さあ

   でも**さ**、母を連れて行かなくてはいけないんだ。

   But, I have to take my mother.