# The difference between ending a sentence with さ or ね

Tags: particles, colloquial-language, sentence-final-particles

According to this [question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1895/ending-a-sentence-with-%E3%81%95), ending a sentence with さ is a colloquial way of to make a sentence more playfully assertive. But I noticed that ね is also used to end a sentence and the meaning to me seems to be the same as the sentence that ends with a さ.

For Example:

> あのさ、これさ美味しいよ
>
> あのね、これね美味しいよ

Is my understanding correct that both can mean as "Hey/You know what, **this** is delicious." If so, then in what situation can ending a sentence with a さ or ね be different.

Comment: Just my two cents, さ sounds more pushy than ね.

Comment: This is quite subtle and there's lots of personal variation, but I'd say that in this context, さ sounds a bit more like it's soliciting a response, whereas ね sounds slightly more "preachy" (no response needed).

Comment: In the mid 90s when I was living in the Tōhoku, it also struck me that their use of さ differed from what I encountered a few years later in the Kantō.  Any chance your samples came from someone specific to a region?

Answer (score 3):

The key differences between the two are:

- あの**さ**、これさ美味しいよ
  **Hey, this is delicious you know. I'm telling you...**  (doesn't care if the Hearer agrees or not)
- あの**ね**、これね美味しいよ
  **Hey, this is delicious, isn't it?** (Speaker is waiting for an agreement from the Hearer)

さ is a sentence-final particle used by males (and I have heard females too) in very colloquial speech to express varying degrees of assertion. A reply isn't expected.

- Encouragement: Q：就職で来るかなあ。A:出来る**さ**。 I wonder if I can get a job? **Sure you can.**
- Negate Someone's Challenge: Q: 君は日本語、読めないよね。A：いや読める**さ**。 You can't read Japanese, right? **Yeah, sure I can.**
- Light Comment: 人生は長い旅のようなもの**さ**。 **Life is something like a long journey.**
- Irritation or Opposition: どうして酒をのんじゃいけないの**さ**。 **How come I can't drink sake?**

ね on the other hand has different functions.

- Request Confirmation from the Hearer: あなたは学生です**ね**。 You are a student, **aren't you?** (speaker is waiting for an answer)
- Request Agreement from the Hearer: A: 今日はいい天気です**ね**。B:本当にそうです**ね**。  Nice weather today, **isn't it?**  Yes, isn't it.