# How to use "なんとかなる" in the context "it's okay, I'll make things okay"?

Tags: grammar, translation, expressions

I want to know how to properly write なんとかなる.
I've seen multiple ways: なんとかなるさ、なんとかなるよ.
I saw something somewhere saying that なんとかなるよ was like saying "everything will be okay" or "I will make it okay".
But somewhere else I saw someone using 大丈夫だよ。なんとかなる as a form of asking and affirming things will be okay, I'll make sure of it.

I want to know how to say that "everything will be fine, I'll make sure of it/I will make it happen" and if なんとかなる is okay and how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases you can use なんとかなる to say 'everything will be fine', but なんとかする might be better when you want to convey that you are really committed to improve the situation.

Literally なんとかなる means something like 'the situation will just take its course; things will go as they go'. It is in 3rd person, more neutral as such, and does not tell whether the speaker really does something.

For example, if you are talking about a work project that is stuck with some problem, you would better tell your supervisor なんとかします because なんとかなります would sound irresponsible or vague.

I think people (like me) tend to use なんとかなる more exactly because it does not put any responsibility on those who say this :). So the distinction is partly psychological, and using なんとかなる does not necessarily mean that the speaker will NOT do anything.

===

**A note on the endings**

The endings よ or さ do not affect the meaning.

Roughly,

- よ in 何とかなるよ indicates that the speaker particularly tries to make the listener be aware that it will be okay.
- 何とかなるさ sounds masculine

If uttered cheerfully, it sounds more optimistic and probably softer than なんとかなる. A possible English parallel is saying it with emphasis on 'will': "Things *will* be fine!"

FYI: なんとかなるわ is a feminine version and なんとかなるわよ is feminine + emphasis same as よ above.

Cf:

- [Ending a sentence with さ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1895/ending-a-sentence-with-%e3%81%95)
- https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/sentence-ending-particles/

Comment: thank you so much ! Can I ask, how does it change when you add  よor さafter なんとかなる?

Comment: Please see the edit. It is a matter of ending particles in general. Hope this helps.